# DoCmd.RunSQL doesn't display a warning

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I chose `DoCmd.RunSQL` for a particular function instead of `CurrentDb.Execute` because I wanted to take advantage of Access's built-in warnings to give the user the option of rolling back a query. As I was running it today, though, I noticed that it no longer displays the warning. I'm almost positive it did when I wrote the procedure.

I've tried explicitly setting `DoCmd.SetWarnings True`, even though there's no reason `SetWarnings` should be off in the first place, but that doesn't solve the problem. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

My code is below (edited lightly to save space). For reference, this is a feature on a context menu that notes the value of a field for the current record, and updates all records in the recordset to the same value. The query it produces is correct, and it executes properly -- but it doesn't display a warning message first.

```
Public Function FillFoundRecords()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim controlField As String, idName As String, _
        commandText As String, whereClause As String

    'First save the current record
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    controlField = Screen.ActiveControl.ControlSource

    With Screen.ActiveForm
        'Check for any where clauses or filters on the active form
        whereClause = GetWhereClause(.RecordSource)

        'Build the UPDATE command. This uses a few custom functions and properties, 
        'but it's not the problem -- it always produces the correct query statement.
        commandText = _
          "UPDATE " & .BaseTable & _
          " SET [" & controlField & "] = " & ActiveControlFilter & _
          " WHERE " & whereClause

        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        DoCmd.RunSQL commandText
        .Refresh
    End With

ExitHandler:
    On Error Resume Next 'Ignore further errors
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 2501 Then 'RunSQL command was cancelled; ignore this
        Resume ExitHandler
    Else
        ErrorHandle
        Resume ExitHandler
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If you save an UPDATE query in Access and then double-click it do you get any warnings?

Comment: Okay, I have no idea what's going on, but it suddenly started working again. I haven't changed anything. I hate it when Access just randomly breaks and then starts working again, but I guess I'll take it. Sorry, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you reported you are now getting the confirmation messages you want from `DoCmd.RunSQL`.  Unfortunately we still don't understand their temporary disappearance.

However if you're depending on those confirmation messages, beware that each user can set the advanced option *"Confirm Action Queries"* based on her own preference and your application will honor her preference.

So, if you want those confirmation messages, revise your application to guarantee the setting is what you need.

```vb
Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", True
```

That change will then persist across Access sessions.  To avoid annoying your users, you can check the setting when your application starts ...

```vb
? Application.GetOption("Confirm Action Queries")
```

... save it, and restore it again at shutdown with `Application.SetOption`.

Comment: That's a fair point. Either that, or just implement my own warnings, which really isn't all that much work. If they're coming and going, I guess better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you got annoyed by the warnings awhile ago and you disabled them?  In the Options menu (I think under the Advanced tab), there are 3 toggles:

Confirm Record Changes
Confirm Document Changes
Confirm Action Queries

Are any of these unchecked?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, they're all checked.

Comment: Sometimes while running thru code that has `docmd.setwarnings false` and later `docmd.setwarnings true`, an error is thrown in between.  In that case, the warning is turned off until you close & reopen or run `docmd.setwarnings true` in the immediate window. Is that what you did when you said you set it explicitly?

Comment: No, if you look at my code, I actually placed `docmd.setwarnings true` _immediately_ before `docmd.runsql` just to be sure that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Perhaps it's returning 0 results to update? If there's nothing to update, then maybe it wouldn't give a warning.

Comment: For an `UPDATE` query executed with `DoCmd.RunSQL` which affects 0 rows, Access 2007 still displays the confirmation message *"You are about to update 0 row(s)."*

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `DoCmd.SetWarnings` in a *long* time, but for what it's worth the following code does raise the warnings just like when I double-click an Action query:

```
Sub queryTest()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "zzzTempQuery"
On Error GoTo queryTest_Error
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("zzzTempQuery", "UPDATE Clients SET LastName=""Thompson"" WHERE ID=25")
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.OpenQuery "zzzTempQuery", acViewNormal
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "zzzTempQuery"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "zzzTempQuery"
Exit Sub

queryTest_Error:
If Err.Number = 2501 Then
    '' user cancelled - just exit
Else
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End If
End Sub
```

### Edit

Hmm, I thought it might have something to do with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, but this variant raises a warning, too:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Clients SET LastName=""Thompson"" WHERE ID=25"
```